# Can I somehow force bitcoind to do decomposition with getblock?

Tags: bitcoind, block

Can I somehow force bitcoin to include the script with `getblock` call?

I see that here https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/886 and here https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=89725.0 there is indicated that it is possible with `'{"tx":"obj", "script":"asm"}'` option, but currently that returns error from bitcoind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the source code here

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/bitcoinrps.cpp
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/rpcblockchain.cpp

and comparing it to the code in the pull request in the question

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/886/files

it seems like it is NOT possible in the code today. Oh well.